# Running Unity Application on Azure VM with Nvidia graphics

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, virtual-machine

I want to run an Environment Simulation, developed with Unity3D (game engine) on an Azure VM. This simulation contains some raytracing and shader computing, which requires a Nvidia graphic card. It's compiled as a windows executable and it runs on my local machine...

For now, I did some tests with the SKUs: "Standard_NC4as_T4_v3" and "Standard_NC6s_v3". The GPU drivers are installed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/hpccompute-gpu-windows)

With both SKUs my App is crashing. This is the output of the logfile:

```
Mono path[0] = 'C:/App/Build/*_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = 'C:/App/Build/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Initialize engine version: 2022.2.1f1 (4fead5835099)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path C:/App/Build/*_Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=0; jobified=0
d3d12: loaded!
Direct3D:
    Version:         Direct3D 12 [level 12.1]
    Renderer:        Microsoft Basic Render Driver (ID=0x8c)
    Vendor:          Microsoft
    VRAM:            14335 MB
    App VRAM Budget: 12902 MB
    Unified Memory Architecture
    Cache Coherent UMA
FMOD initialized on nosound output
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
- Loaded All Assemblies, in  4.962 seconds
- Finished resetting the current domain, in  0.002 seconds
Dedicated video D3D11 device creation failed (error: 0x887a0004). This device is used specifically for video decoding, we will use software video decoding instead.
UnloadTime: 0.949400 ms
D3D12Fence::Wait(9) error: got 8. Possible device removal.
Crash!!!
SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: '.;C:\App\Build;C:\App\Build;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;', symOptions: 534, UserName: 'adminuser'
OS-Version: 10.0.0
```

I'm surprised to read here that the renderer is "Microsoft Basic Render Driver". The Device Manager got the GPU correctly:

[image]

Also the console output about the GPU looks good:
[image]

It is a bit confusing to me, that the Nvidia Control Panel, doesn't allow me to control anything. Here I expect to see more control options about the GPU:

[image]

Operating System:

```
source_image_reference {
  publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
  offer     = "WindowsServer"
  sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
  version   = "latest"
}
```

What am I missing? Why does my app keep crashing?

Comment: can you right click and run with a different renderer (i know when my laptop had 2 you could pick but by default it used the crap one for desktop) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I think it's about the SKU I used.

1. GPU Acceleration should be enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/enable-gpu-acceleration
2. There are some SKUs with GPUs only for AI purposes. These Nvidia GPUs can only be operated in TCC mode. For rendering graphics, I need WDDM Mode. For some SKUs this mode can be switched (up to now, I think there is none of these switchable SKUs in my region?).

For me, this problem could be solved by using SKU: Standard_NV6ads_A10_v5

If anyone else has problems regarding this, see this Youtube Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiRyc26_lds